# ExtJs Grid.Panel does not sort java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, sql, sorting, extjs, timestamp

I use Ext JS 4.1 in a Java EE Webapplication.

I have a Ext.grid.Panel where some dates are shown.
The dates are are stored in DB2. So my Pojo uses java.sql.Timestamp.

The Ext.data.Model looks like:

```
Ext.define('schedulerTask', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'histTimestamp',
        type : 'date',
        sortType : 'asDate'
    }]
});
```

And the Panel looks like:

```
var schedulerTasksHistGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title : 'History',
    store : schedTaskHistStore,
    columns : [ {
        text : "No:",
        xtype : 'rownumberer',
        width : 30
            }, {
        xtype : 'datecolumn',
        format : 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
        text : "histTimestamp",
        dataIndex : 'histTimestamp'
    }],

    renderTo : 'grid_sched_tasks_hist'
});
```

When I want to sort the histTimestamp it does not sort correctly.
I read that I should specify in Ext.Data.Model.fields a dateFormat. Is this correct and how should I specify it?

Comment: How do you load the models data? In particular, what date format does your server spits out? The model field's `dateFormat` option must be configured to match this.

Comment: The format in DB is: '2009-06-18-20.56.02.000000'. But the Server seems to convert it to the following format: 'Feb 4, 2013 2:11:58 PM' (inspected with Firebug GET Regquest)

Comment: That's indeed the format you see in the response (i.e. Firebug) that counts. You'll find Ext date format specs in [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Date). Now, what you've passed doesn't seem like a good format for machine parsing (it should be '2013-02-04 14:11:58' or '2013-02-04T14:11:58', with timezone if needed, in my opinion); you should probably tweak your server to output something like that.

Comment: Is it better to use milliseconds or a real date well formated?

Comment: I let the server return the timestamp in milliseconds and use in ExtJs 'time' as dateFormat. It parses and formts correctly but the sort does not works either. In particular, the date 30-10-2013 ... is still on top.

Comment: I found out the problem. There was a groupField in my store. I didnt see this. Without grouping it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. There was a groupField in my store. Removing this field solved the issue.